# Compare duplicate values of two select in materializecss framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, materialize

I have two select boxes and i dont want that the user choose the same value in both.

I've tried some solution proposed on stack, but the materialized select is different from "normal select" as contains the options in list item elements.

However, i came up with a solution, which is all but elegant, i know..im a novice with these things.

But its not working as i intended.
I want to create an additional method for jquery validation plugin, in the example on fiddle i've inserted an additional field to show the error placement.
I think is pretty simple, but i just can't figure out how to do it...

```
  $.validator.addMethod("checksameval", function(value, element) {
  return $('#pref1').val() == $('#pref2').val()
}, "Pref1 and Pref2 cant have same value!");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L24otmaa/5/

edited with custom method (still not working..)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that the form will still be valid and therefore it will be possible to send it anyway.

You have to add a custom validation. The plug-in offers a callback where you can check whatever you want before you finally submit it.
This can be done by adding your validation to a custom submit handler

```
 var isSameValue = function() {
      var val1 = $('#pref1').val();
      var val2 = $('#pref2').val();
      if (val1 == val2) {
        $customErrorDiv.text('error you cant select same value twice!!');
        return true;
      } 
      $customErrorDiv.text('');
      return false;
  }

 // check also on runtime
 $('.course').change( function() {
     isSameValue();
  });

 $("#application").validate({
    // check before submitting
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       if (isSameValue()) {
          return;
        }
        // submit the form manually
        form.submit();
     }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7uhkddrx/

Documentation: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Of course you would have to style this message according to your needs.

EDIT: By the way: currently your select boxes are not set to be required.

EDIT2: added checking on runtime

Comment: Yeah i wanted to create an additional method with validate,i just created one for alphabetic chars only,you can see it in action on the fiddle below. 
I know in the fiddle selects are not required, in the original form they are.
 
is it possible to have the error display at runtime (e.g. jsfiddle.net/L24otmaa/4) when i insert numeric value into filler field when i focus out the field i get the error.

Comment: I edited my post for also runtime validation. I don't know about adding methods with this plug-in, so maybe there is a more beautiful solution to make this work. Anyway it does what you want, right?